# SP 2010 Office Web Apps question

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, security, configuration-wizard, owa

I had a quick question. We are in the process of remediation vulnerabilities in our existing SP 2010 environment (Both Windows and SP)

There are two updates below that we need to install for SP 2010

**Microsoft Office and Microsoft Office Services and Web Apps Security Update September 2018
Microsoft Office and Microsoft Office Services and Web Apps Security Update August 2018**

My question is do we need to run the configuration wizard for the web apps security updates?

Regards
Vj

Comment: which KB numbers are you referring? could you please give us that?

Comment: KB4022207, KB4032215 and KB4032220

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to run the config wizard after the installing the above updates, As rule of thumb when ever apply any updates in SharePoint 2010 farm, please run the psconfig wizard to complete the update process.

[Why we recommend / require to run the Configuration Wizard also for Security fixes](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2015/09/09/why-we-recommend-require-to-run-the-configuration-wizard-also-for-security-fixes/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing update for SharePoint 2010, as Waqas said, you need to run the config wizard after install update for SharePoint 2010.

You don't need to run the Config Wizard after every update, just when the last one is applied.

If you are installing update for Office Web Apps, you don't need to run the config wizard.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/officeonlineserver/apply-software-updates-to-office-online-server